# Where can I have a node.js server hosted

Tags: node.js, web-hosting

I currently have a website where I need to use node.js, I am not able to use node.js however, because the web host does not support it. What is the best way I go about hosting a server without having to completely change hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> […] without having to completely change hosts?

If your current hosting provider doesn't support nodejs and you want to use nodejs, then you have to change hosting provider. Sorry.

I can recommend [Google Cloud Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute/). You can create a virtual machine, e.g. running Fedora, access it via SSH and install what you need, i.e. `apache2`, `nodejs`, etc.

If you're not comfortable with that, you should go for a managed hosting solution instead. It will probably be a little more expensive, and you'll have less flexibility in what programs you can use (since you share your virtual machine with other customers and can't make changes to the system yourself), but on the upside, most of the setup is done for you. There are many providers you can choose from; google "managed hostinig with nodejs" if you want an overview. I have used [1and1](https://1and1.com) before and was mostly happy with it. As you can see [here](https://www.1and1.co.uk/cloud-app-centre/node-js-download#apps), they have nodejs installed on their servers.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes hardly any sense... but

[Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/nodejs) is really great for Node.js app hosting